# Resize content of UIScrollView when zooming

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, resize, zooming, image-resizing

I know there is many topics for this subject but I didn't found a good solution for my problem.
I have a UIScrollView with an image and other components added as subviews. 
I just want to know the good way to resize the components into in real time when I zoom.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Resizing image and other components
}
```

**EDIT** : I would like the impression that the components inside the scroll view keep the same size when I zoom. I don't want to they become bigger or smaller during zooming.

**EDIT** : Here is the hierarchy of my UIViewController

- View

  - ScrollView

    - Main view

      - Image view
      - Drawing view (UIView with components like UILabel, other UIViews, etc...)

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I would leave the scale of UIScrollView as it is and reach the goal with the help of subview (adjusting its size, not scrollView's), where I would place all the subviews and the images you work with. 
So it would be something like:

```
yourView.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(newScale, newScale, 1.0);
```

where *yourView* is the main (only) subview of scrollView. Then I would recalculate the size of the *yourView* with new scale and set it to scrollView's *contentSize* parameter so that you could actually scroll the enlarged content, not only see it truncated.

The only thing is that in this case you should use the callback other than *scrollViewDidZoom:* I guess.

P.S. Changing UIView's *transform* parameter you don't need to bother about subviews' scale: CoreAnimation does everything for you.

Comment: It's CGAffineTransformScale and not CATransform3DMakeScale. Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Besides, I edited my question. I would like the impression that the components inside the scroll view keep the same size when I zoom. I don't want to they become bigger or smaller during zooming.

Comment: Whichever you prefer, but in your case CGAffineTransformScale is indeed better. What concerns your edition: as far as I see your task, you need not actually to zoom in/out your scrollView, but more replace subviews in it properly after increasing its *contentSize*. So you could set *scrollView.contentSize* in your callback (this callback doesn't give you the scale itself, so it's another question how to find the value to zoom to) and position (changing frame.origin) the subviews.

Comment: Yes, but when I zoom on the scroll view (in order to grow the image into), the other components into are automatically  bigger/smaller. How can I avoid this ?

Comment: I edited my question in order to show the hierarchy of mu UIViewController.

Comment: Hm, if you have a value of new scale, you could just calculate the inverse one and apply it to your drawingView (which should remain with its old size), like: *inverseScale = oldScale/newScale;*  And then (for drawingView) *CGAffineTransformScale(transform, inverseScale, inverseScale);*  Also try to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636384/scale-uiview-without-scaling-subviews

Comment: When I apply the transform CGAffineTransformScale(transform, inverseScale, inverseScale) to each component of my drawing view, it doesn't do anything.. :/

Comment: Try drawingView.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(inverseScale, inverseScale, 1.0); then. Without code I cannot say what's wrong there.