# Using CGAffineTransform to scale up the view, but not for child views

Tags: swift, cgaffinetransform

I want to scale up my view, without changing the size of its child views. 
Here is my codes

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.3, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: { [weak self] in             
    self?.myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
})
```

I tried to avoid it by making false `autoresizesSubviews` and `clipTobound`,  but they are not working for me. 
could anyone help me on that?
Many Thanks

Comment: Can't you add a secondary view under your `myView` that you will scale ? Set your view container invisible. Then it will make the illusion that your `myView` is scaled ? Otherwise please provide an example of your view hierarchy.

Comment: I have many items that contains UiViews and some stackviews on that view. This vew first moved to the center and then get bigger. I can use another method to get it bigger, but I don't know why when I use another things, the view moves back to its first position, which should'nt

Comment: View's child views will scale too based on the auto-layout constraints that you have set up for the main view.

Comment: Why not scaling your subViews down then? Like: self?.myView.yourSubview.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5) in the same animation block.

Comment: I tried that, even with inverse, it will be good, but its constraint changes as well and not fit as before, then I tried to change the constraint to make it fit again, but nothing will change.

Comment: Check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636384/scale-uiview-without-scaling-subviews .    Hope it helps.